# How to modify the `print` function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

The `print` function is defined in both these files:

> flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/core/print.dart
>
> flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/core/print.dart

I opened each of them and modified the function to add this line at the start

```dart
if (kDebugMode) return;
```

I restarted the IDE, run the app with this code

```dart
print(kDebugMode); // Prints true
```

The `print` function shouldn't have printed anything. If I go and check the implementation of those `print` function, my `if` condition line is still there.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly you try'ng to achieve?

Comment: @OMiShah I was just wondering why the `print` still prints.

Comment: Modifying those files probably doesn't help because they're probably compiled and cached somewhere.  In addition to [using `runZoned` as Remi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76003886/), for Flutter you should be using [`debugPrint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html), an assignable property that you can set to your own implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to modify the source code anyway.
Instead, you can use `Zone` to override the `print` behavior in your code without modifying the SDK.

You can do:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runZoned(
    () => print('Hello world'),
    zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
      print: (self, parent, zone, line) {
        // Your logic here:
        // if (kDebugMode) return;
        // Now use the original print implementation:
        parent.print(zone, 'This is a custom print: $line');
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

This example overrides `print` to customize the output. In this example, even though we called `print('Hello world')`, the output will be `This is a custom print: Hello world`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of not changing the source file part but I was just curious to know why it didn't work as intended. But this is definitely the right approach.